# How to fix code completion using DocBlock type hints with Intelephense?

Tags: php, visual-studio-code, autocomplete, intelephense

I'm trying to get better completion with the VSCode extension Intelephense and some things aren't making sense.  To start here is some example code:

```php
<?php
declare(strict_types=1);

// "square/square": "30.0.0.20230816"
use Square\SquareClient;
use Square\Models\CatalogObject;
use Square\Models\CatalogItem;

require 'vendor/autoload.php';

$client = new SquareClient([
    'accessToken' => $_ENV['SQUARE_ACCESS_TOKEN'],
    'environment' => 'sandbox'
]);

$res = $client->getCatalogApi()->listCatalog();

/* @var CatalogObject[] $catalog */
$catalog = $res->getResult()->getObjects();

if ($catalog) {

    /* @var CatalogObject $item */
    foreach ($catalog as $item) {

        /* @var CatalogItem $data */
        $data = $item->getItemData();

    }
}
```

I get completion on `$client->getCatalogApi()` after scrolling past all global symbols & methods.  I'd love to remove them because `$client->$_COOKIE` just doesn't seem helpful.

Second and more importantly I get why the type can't be determined for `$catalog`, `$item` and `$data` but it appears like hinting as I've done with `@var <Type> $variable` is supported by Intelephense but it's having no affect with Intelephense 1.9.5 (I've re-indexed).  What I'm expecting is if I type for example `$data->getItem` one of the choices will be `$data->getItemData()`.  Thank you!

VSCode 1.81.1.
Intelephense 1.9.5 (paid).
PHP 8.2.

Answer (score 0):

So the answer to this question for me was a result of two issues.  The first was code completion being "polluted" with a ton of items from the global namespace so even in situations where the completion had the right answer I had to scroll past all the globals to get to it.  Here's an example:

[image: example of code completion returning global items]

To get rid of the globals you just have to disable [VSCodes built-in PHP support](https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/languages/php):

> To disable the built-in PHP smart completions in favor of suggestions
> from an installed PHP extension, uncheck **PHP > Suggest: Basic**, which
> sets `php.suggest.basic` to false in your settings.json file.

The other issue I was bumping into is PHP [Intelephense](https://intelephense.com/) does not appear to support PHPDoc type hints (v1.9.5).  To fix this I just installed the [PHPActor LSP](https://phpactor.readthedocs.io/en/master/index.html) along with the [VSCode extension](https://phpactor.readthedocs.io/en/master/lsp/vscode.html) which does understand the type hints.